# Define_Module() throws an error | C++ | Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

There is an error in Define_Module(OLT) when i try to build my code.

Am i doing something wrong?

D:\omnetpp-4.6\ptixiaki\XGPON/OLT.cc:18: undefined reference to `OLT::OLT()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//XGPON.exe] Error 1
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'out/gcc-debug//XGPON.exe' failed

```
//XGPON.NED
 package xgpon;
 import ned.DelayChannel;
 import ned.IdealChannel;


 simple OLT
 {
@display("i=device/mainframe");
gates:
    input splitter_to_OLT;
    output OLT_to_splitter;

    }

simple Splitter
{
@display("i=device/modem");
gates:
    input ONU_splitter[];
    input OLT_splitter;
    output splitter_OLT;
    output splitter_ONU[];

}

 simple ONU
 {
@display("i=device/laptop");
gates:
    input splitter_to_ONU;
    output ONU_to_splitter;
 }


 network XGPON
{
parameters:
    @display("bgb=550,234;i=block/network2");
    int n_nodes = 6;


types:
    channel upstream extends ned.DatarateChannel
    {
        datarate = 2.48832 Gbps; //datarate of the channel
    }

    channel downstream extends ned.DatarateChannel
    {
        datarate = 9.95328 Gbps; //datarate of the channel
    }


submodules:
    splitter: Splitter {
        @display("p=258,109");
    }
    olt: OLT {
        @display("p=57,59");
    }
    onu: ONU {
        @display("p=393,87");
    }
connections:
    
    olt.OLT_to_splitter --> downstream -->splitter.OLT_splitter;
    splitter.splitter_OLT --> downstream --> onu.splitter_to_ONU;
    
    splitter.splitter_ONU++ --> upstream --> olt.splitter_to_OLT;
    onu.ONU_to_splitter --> upstream --> splitter.ONU_splitter++;
}



    



  //OLT.H
     #ifndef OLT_H_
     #define OLT_H_
     #include <omnetpp.h>
    #include <string.h>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include "Packet_m.h"
     #include "DownstreamFrame_m.h"
     #include "UpstreamFrame_m.h"
     #define FRAME_TIME 691.2


 class OLT : public cSimpleModule
 {
private:
    int source;
    //int destination;
    simsignal_t arrivalSignal;

    int no_sent;
    int no_rcvd;



    cMessage *DownstreamFrameSendEvent, *NewPacketArrivalEvent;
    simtime_t sendTimeout, bufferTimeout;
    XGPONpacket *downFragment;
    cPacketQueue *OLTBuffer;
    std::vector<double> distance, RTT, BandwidthUtilizationProfile, AllocationWeight;
    //std::vector<long double> accumulatedRequestedBandwidth , accumulatedAllocatedBandwidth;
    std:: vector<int> upstreamBandwidthDemands, DownPacketsForONU, destination;
    int oltId, numberOfOnus, headerSize, PSBd, parityBytes, PLOAMdMessages, FrameQueueSize, fragmentBytes, BWMap;
    //int FixedGuarandeedBandwidth, totalUpstreamBandwidth, AssuredGuarandeedBandwidth, firstPhaseNonGuarandeedBandwidth;
    //long double totalBytesCreated, totalBytesReceived, SumDelay, SquareSumDelay, totalUpDelay, SumBUP;
    //double ABU, ProtectionParameter, OverloadedOnusAllocationWeighSum, UpdatingImpact, SW;

    double ONU_time_counter ; /* a local time counter for file results */
    double variate; /* the final exponenetial variate (interarrivals) */
    double sum_variate ; /* used to compute the experimental mean for variate */
    double sum_rnd; /* used to compute the experimental mean for UD */
    long loops ; /* counter for loops */
    long pkt_per_time_unit ; /* nb of pkts per unit of time */
    double time; /* our simulated time in us */
    double mean,start_pktime,ref_time,end_pktime;
    double rnd_nb; /* the uniform random number */

public :
    OLT();
    virtual ~OLT();

protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
    virtual XGPONpacket *generatePacket();
    virtual void generateFrame(cPacketQueue *queue);
    //virtual void generateHeader(cPacketQueue *queue);
    virtual void forwardFrame(XGPONpacket *msg);
    virtual void finish();





    //virtual int defragmentation(cPacketQueue *queue);



 };

 #endif /* OLT_H_ */



 //OLT.CC
 #include "OLT.h"

 Define_Module(OLT); //the error is here

      void OLT::initialize()
  {
    numberOfOnus = 6;

    cPacketQueue* OLTBuffer = new cPacketQueue("OLTBuffer");

    for(int i = 0; i<= numberOfOnus; i++){
        OLTBuffer->insert(generatePacket());
        XGPONpacket *packet = (XGPONpacket *) OLTBuffer->pop();
        //Distance
        distance.push_back(destination.at(i) + 20);
        EV << "My distance is " << distance[i] << " numbers.\n \n";
        EV << "My destination is " << packet->getDestination()/2 << ".\n \n";

        //RTT
        RTT.push_back(distance.at(i) / 3*(10^8));
        EV << "My RTT is " <<  RTT[i] << " numbers.\n \n";

    }
    EV << "My buffer size is " << OLTBuffer->getLength() << " numbers.\n \n";
    //generateFrame(OLTBuffer);

  }


  void OLT::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
  {
XGPONpacket *ttmsg = check_and_cast<XGPONpacket *>(msg);

forwardFrame(ttmsg);

 }

 void OLT::generateFrame(cPacketQueue *OLTBuffer)
 {

    DownFrame *queue = new DownFrame();
    //Fmqueue Fmqueue;
    queue->~DownFrame();

    //FrameQueueSize = queue -> getFrameSize();

    //cPacketQueue *queue = new cPacketQueue();
    //FrameQueueSize = 155520;

   for(int i=0 ; i <OLTBuffer->getLength(); i++)
          {
       //EV << "GAMW TI MANA SOU " << OLTBuffer->getLength() << " numbers.\n \n";
              XGPONpacket *packet = (XGPONpacket *) OLTBuffer->pop();
              simtime_t waitingTime = simTime() - packet->getCreationTime();
              double processTime = (packet->getBitLength()/(9.95328 * pow (10,9))) +      (RTT.at(packet->getDestination())/2);
              simtime_t receptTime = waitingTime + processTime;
              packet->setReceptionTime(receptTime);
              EV << "<<<<<<< OLT (id =" << oltId << ") : Packet " << packet->getName() <<           "reception time:" << packet->getReceptionTime() << ">>>>> \n";
              OLTBuffer -> insert(packet);
                }

             while ((queue->getByteLength() < FrameQueueSize) && (OLTBuffer->isEmpty() == false))
              {
              XGPONpacket *max = (XGPONpacket *) OLTBuffer->pop();

              for(int i=0; i<OLTBuffer->length(); i++)
                  {

                  XGPONpacket *data = (XGPONpacket *) OLTBuffer->pop();

                  if(max->getReceptionTime() >= data->getReceptionTime())
                      {
                          OLTBuffer -> insert(data);
                      }
                  else
                      {
                          OLTBuffer->insert(max);
                          max = data->dup();
                          delete data;
                      }
                  }
              EV <<"<<<< OLT (id =" << oltId <<") : Packet " << max->getName() << " reception time:" << max->getReceptionTime() << "inserted to frame >>>>\n";
              queue->insert(max);
           }

 }

 XGPONpacket *OLT::generatePacket()
 {
// Produce source and destination addresses.
//source = getIndex();   // our module index

//Destinationn

int time_limit = 60;


for(source = 1; source <= numberOfOnus-1; source++)
{
    ONU_time_counter = 0;
    pkt_per_time_unit = 0;
    sum_variate = 0;
    sum_rnd = 0;
    loops = 0;

    time=0;

    destination.push_back(intuniform(2,numberOfOnus-1));

    start_pktime=0.7;
    end_pktime=12.7; //1gb prepei na brw transmision time

    mean = start_pktime;
    ref_time = time;

            while( time < time_limit )
            {
                if(ONU_time_counter >= FRAME_TIME)
                {
                    mean = (double) mean +(end_pktime - start_pktime)/((time_limit - ref_time)/FRAME_TIME);
                    ONU_time_counter = ONU_time_counter - FRAME_TIME;

                    /* prints the nb of pkts / unit time */
                    //fprintf(files1, "\n%ld", pkt_per_time_unit);
                    pkt_per_time_unit = 0;
                }
                //rnd_nb = (random()/limit); /* the random number 0<= x <=1 */
                rnd_nb =  uniform(0,1);
                /* compute the IAT */

                variate = (-mean)*log(rnd_nb); /* Poisson IAT */
                //wait(variate);

                XGPONpacket *msg = new XGPONpacket();
                msg->setSource(source);
                msg->setDestination(destination[source]);
                msg->setByteLength(intuniform(64,1518));
                return msg;
            }
     }

 }

 void OLT::forwardFrame(XGPONpacket *msg)
 {

// Same routing as before: random gate.
int n = gateSize("out");
//int k = destination;

//EV << "Forwarding message " << msg << " on gate[" << k << "]\n";
send(msg, "out");
 }



 void OLT::finish()
 {
//recordScalar("#sent", no_sent);
//recordScalar("received", no_rcvd);
 }
```

Comment: Have you defined `OLT::OLT()`?  I see that constructor _declared_, but it doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in this code.

Comment: Doesn't it declared with Define_Module(OLT) in OLT.cc file? or i need to do something else?

Comment: No, Define_Module just registers the constructor with the kernel. You still have to DEFINE both the constructor and the destructor in cour .cc file.

Comment: May you help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In `OLT.CC` add at least an empty constructor and destructor:

```
OLT::OLT() {    
}

OLT::~OLT() {    
}
```